# ExtJS inherit config

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extjs, constructor, subclass

In ExtJS 6.2, does subclasses inherit the parent config?

It doesn't seem to work for me.

```js
Ext.define('test1', {
    config: {
        test1: {
            test1: ''
        }
    },

    constructor(config) {
        Ext.apply(this, config);

        console.log(config);
    },
});

Ext.define('test2', {
    extend: 'test1',

    config: {
        test2: ''
    },

    constructor(config) {
        this.callParent(config);

        console.log(this.config);
    },
});

Ext.create('test2', {
    test1: {
        test1: 'test1'
     },
     test2: 'test2'
});
```

Also it seems that on parent constructor `config` is `undefined`!

I want to have everything defined on parent class config also available in child class. And be able to set parent config when creating child class.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3fud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initConfig to get the ExtJS typical configs. You get all configs inside test2.

```
Ext.define('test1', {
    config: {
        test1: null
    },

    constructor(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);

        return this;
    }
});

Ext.define('test2', {
    extend: 'test1',

    config: {
        test2: ''
    },

    constructor(config) {
// == > config

        this.callParent([config]);

// ==> her you can even use getTest1(), setTest1() (or test2)
    }
});

Ext.create('test2', {
    test1: {
        test1: 'test1'
    },
    test2: 'test2'
});
```

Comment: But how do I keep default parent defined config? What if I don't pass `test1` config when I create `test2`?

Comment: I want everything from `test1` to be in `test2`, including config.

Comment: Let me know if this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3fvs) answers your question

Comment: Updated Code inside the answer

Comment: Yes, it does. I remember now having problems before because the config parameter must be an array, that's why it was `NULL` on `test1` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to call `Ext.apply(this, config);` not sure if this is the correct solution.

```js
Ext.define('test2', {
    extend: 'test1',

    config: {
        test2: ''
    },

    constructor(config) {
        this.callParent(config);

        Ext.apply(this, config);  // <-

        console.log(this.config);

        console.log(this.getTest1());
        console.log(this.getTest2());
    },
});
```